# How to convert this timestamp to a more readable form in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, timestamp

My mongo timestamp is this `2020-04-07T07:11:12.922+00:00`.

I want the date to be like, 07 april, 2020 I also need to have time like 07:11:12.

Comment: Check out javascritp Date object references https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://momentjs.com/ . This is a great library to transform any date format to whatever you want.

```js
  function convert() {
    $('#newDate').text(moment($('#date').val()).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    $('#newDate2').text(moment($('#date').val()).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
  }

$( document ).ready(function() {
  convert();
  $('#convert').click(function(){convert()})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text value="2020-04-07T07:11:12.922+00:00" id="date" /> <input type="button" id="convert" value="Convert" />
<div id="newDate"></div>
<div id="newDate2"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. So, momentjs is used for this purpose only? or some other purpose too.

Comment: You can use it to convert a formatted date to another format. Read the doc, it's magic: https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
Let d=new Date(timestamp.getHighBits()*1000);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the library [Momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Basically your db response, say: `res` would be formatted like:

```
const date = moment(res).format('LLL');
console.log(date);
```

This would return something like `moment(10 de abril de 2020 4:01 PM)`. This will depend on the locale you set to moment.js or your machine locale.

```js
const date = document.getElementById('date');
date.value = moment().format('LLL');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<input type=text value="" id="date" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For converting timestamps into date and time format you can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) which is a JavaScript library. 
You can install the package in your project and import the moment library in the file as required.

```
 //importing in react
   import moment from "moment";

//importing in node
   var moment = require('moment');
```

As per your mentioned format you can get the desired output by using the following  syntax:

```
 //for getting date from timestamp: Output: 07 April, 2020

  moment("2020-04-07T07:11:12.922+00:00").format("DD MMMM, YYYY")

 //for getting time from timestamp in desired format

  moment("2020-04-07T07:11:12.922+00:00").format("hh:mm:ss")
```

For exploring other syntax and formats you can read the official docs at : https://momentjs.com/docs/